# How to get the Device ID from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I get the unique ID of the user's device in an iOS app?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

use this

```
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
```

---

**Update**

Apple has the deprecated unique identifier, so now the following code (from Melvin Sovereign's comment) is appropriate:

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Comment: So what are you supposed to use now? Or is there no way to identify a unique device at all anymore?

Comment: New ios5+ way: `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]`

Comment: i think you will get different values each time you get identifierForVendor

Comment: Yeah each time you reinstall the app you will get new UUID

Comment: should the resulted `UUIDString` be cached or is it inexpensive to obtain?

Comment: does this device id can change ??

Comment: Notice : this is not UDID of the device. It's a generated relatively unique ID based on vendor and device. But if you remove all apps from the same vendor and reinstall again, it will be re-generated. Which means, it will change.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, Apple has since deprecated the uniqueIdentifier in iOS 5. Here's the relevant TechCrunch article:
http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/19/apple-ios-5-phasing-out-udid/

Apple suggests that you no longer uniquely identify the device but instead identify the *user*. In most cases, this is excellent advice though there are some situations which still require a **globally** unique device ID. These scenarios are quite common in advertising. Hence, I wrote an extremely simple drop-in library which replicates the existing behavior exactly.

In a shameless plug of self promotion, I'll link it here in the hope that someone finds it useful. Also, I welcome all and any feedback/criticism:
http://www.binpress.com/app/myid/591

Answer (score 3):

I think this code may help you ;)

`NSString * id = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;`

You can also have a look to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: Interestingly, Apple has since deprecated the uniqueIdentifier in iOS 5. Here's the relevant TechCrunch article:
http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/19/apple-ios-5-phasing-out-udid/  
Apple suggests that you no longer uniquely identify the device but instead identify the *user*. In most cases, this is excellent advice though there are some situations which require a __globally__ unique device ID. These scenarios are quite common advertising.

Comment: In iOS 7+ use: NSString *identifer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSUUID *identifierForVendor`

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift

```
var uniqueId=UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString as String
println("Your device identifires =>\(uniqueId)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this is a pretty old question, but this is how i solve the problem. It might fail, if the thread creating the "unique device token" never stops, but it worked for me.

```
-(NSString*)getUniqueDeviceToken
{
    __block NSString* UDTToReturn = @"UDTCouldNotBeCreatedSuccessfully,PlatformNotSupported,Simulator,iOSVer<11";
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphoretowaitforudtcreation = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    if ([DCDevice.currentDevice isSupported])
    {
        [DCDevice.currentDevice generateTokenWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                UDTToReturn = error.description;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoretowaitforudtcreation);
            }
        
            else
            {
                UDTToReturn = [token base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoretowaitforudtcreation);
            }
        }];
    }
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoretowaitforudtcreation, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
return UDTToReturn;
}
```

Comment: What is this code doing? Is it gets the unique id of the device, or just generates a uuid? Also: Is there a Swift version?

Comment: I created/use this code to create a "unique device token" and save it to a local file on my iOS-Devices (iPhone, iPad). Apple doesn't allow developers to use the "uuid" since 201? . In a certain way you could say that it creates a device-specific-number, but it might change, when you reinstall an app on your device. The code only exists in obj-c-code, but can be also/easily used in swift. The whole "identify device"-topic is not that easy to understand. If you want some kind "using information" of your app, you have to register to "APNs".