# Get Apple/Google ID for replacing email address in user account - feasability and sense?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, registration

I'm currently planning on creating an app. Unfortunately the need for usercreation is there. I know users don't like goind through a registration process with opt in by email activation link click.

So I thought maybe using the apple/google id as a replacement for email address would be cool since the verification step by email can be dropped. In addition when the user changes his or her mail address that's no problem since his or her id doesn't change in this case.

I'm not really into this particular topic so I have some questions, any help is highly appreciated:

1. Is there any numeric/alphanumeric id anyway or is the google/apple id (i.e. the "username") the email address itself?
2. Is this possible in Android and Apple SDK (and Cordova in addition since I use this one)?
3. Is this a good idea in general or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below DeviceIDs solutions as primary key for your users registrations. Look:

***1 - Android***

**1.1 - Android Phones (With SIM chip) -** For Android I use the Cordova SIM plugin. It generates uniqueIDs for devices based on SIM chip informations. So, you can manipulate your data based on the plugins return;

Link: https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim

**1.2 - Adroid Tablets -** The plugin above is fantastic, but it does not work for devices that does not have any SIM chip. In this case, I use the following code:

```
   if(mContext == null){
        mContext = this.cordova.getActivity();
        if(dialog == null){
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        }
    }

    String tabletID = Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

**Conclusion:** If you are developing only for phones (App projected for Mobile Phone) you should use the plugin. If your App targets Tablets or devices without SIM card, than you can take a look at the other solution. The IDs generated are "Devices ID", unique for each device.

***2 - iOS***

For iOS, I use the following code to generate an unique ID for each device:

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

The only problem: When user uninstalls all Apps of your iTunes vendor ID from the device and installs any of them again, the ID will be changed. Other easy ways to get Unique ID for iOS is deprecated since version 7.0 of the system.

See more here: [Device Id from an iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468629/device-id-from-an-iphone-app)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since payed subscriptions are connected to the user account this doesn't seem to be a possible solution. If I get a new Device the information is gone :-(

Comment: Have you ever heard about FireBase Db? You can create unique IDs for each user and sync the data easily using javascript for your cordova projects. In addition, if you use this solution, the ID will be UNIQUE across protaforms

Comment: Mhm, but when the user buys a new phone, all this information is gone in this case, too, isn't it!?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that you will need at least an e-mail as primary information for this solution too.

Comment: In fact the plan had been that I don't even need a mail address since the user account is linked with the apple/google id.