# Check if an ios device was blocked

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Is there a way to identify a device which was blocked by my app, so they cannot create a second account?

I have read a little bit about Unique Identification and DeviceCheck, Apple's own IPA. I also considered to ask for the phone number when the user signs up, but this seems a little complicated for me and the other solutions only work if the user is kind enough no to reinstall the app.

On other approach I had was to get some information (Carrier, iPhone Name, iOS Version, iPhone Model etc.), pack it into one String and use it as an unique id, but some of this information can be changed easily and I don't think Apple would like this solution.

I am sure that there are better/simpler solutions.

(This task seems very easy in Android. I plan to use this statement: `UUID.randomUUID().toString();`)

That info could help:
I am planning to connect this app to Firebase.

In the best case, the solution would work from iOS 8.0 to the current iOS Version.
I am open for any kind of creative solution in Swift or Objective C.

Comment: You can also use UUID in iOS, see if this helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468629/device-id-from-an-iphone-app

Or you can try to add a phone verification for each account and block the phone number

Comment: Does the UUID change when the app is uninstalled and reinstalled?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this by using `SSKeychain`. Using SSKeychain once we have set value for particular in the `SSkeychain` then that value will remain their even we have removed that application from your ios device.

Please check following e.g **Objective- C**

```
 if([SSKeychain passwordForService:@"your application bundle identifier" account:@"user"] == nil)
            {
                    NSString *UUID = AppDelegate.GetUUID;
                    [SSKeychain setPassword:UUID forService:@"your application bundle identifier" account:@"user"];
                    NSString *retrieveuuid = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"your application bundle identifier" account:@"user"];
                    NSLog(@"retrieveuuid %@",retrieveuuid);
            }
    + (NSString *)GetUUID {
            CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
            CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
            CFRelease(theUUID);
            return (__bridge NSString *)string;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definetly try this.

Comment: I have one question just to be sure. There is no way the user can manually delete or edit this entry, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no any such way to edit and delete it manually, we can do that only through coding.